# Data Image URI not working

Tags: uri

I am trying to optimize my page by replacing image urls with DATA-URI but the images are not rendering after converting to DATA URI.

Here is my code to converting normal urls to data uri:

```
$imgurl= "https://www.cashy.in/images/banners/0ad08aafdd0887ed79f9fcc4321d54ed.png";
$type=substr($imgurl, -3);
$newimg=base64_encode($imgurl);
$o_img="data:image/".$type.";base64,".$newimg;
```

Comment: You don't base64 encode the URL, you have to encode the image data itself. Something like `base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgurl));`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above, you don't encode the URL of the image itself, you have to encode the actual data.

As such, you should use something like the following code:

```
$imgurl= "https://www.cashy.in/images/banners/0ad08aafdd0887ed79f9fcc4321d54ed.png";
$type=substr($imgurl, -3);
$newimg=base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgurl));
$o_img="data:image/".$type.";base64,".$newimg;
```

However, when doing this you need to understand that you are increasing the size of your generated HTML by the size of the image (plus the 33% overhead inherent in base64 encoding). Only do this when the image itself is very small and the overheads of an extra HTTP request outweigh the extra download required.